# Validating security token once per page in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a layout that is applied to all pages which require users to be logged on.

In this layout, there are two views being rendered. A partial view displaying user info (named `CurrentUser`) and the main body view.

In the controller for `CurrentUser`, I check for user tokens stored in cookies and redirect to another route if authorization fails. In case of success, an entry is placed in `TempData` so other controllers/actions can access it.

Please note that the `CurrentUser` partial view is placed before any other views on the page. So my assumption was that subsequent controllers would have access to the data in `TempData` but they do not. Other controllers seem to be firing before the `CurrentUser` controller is ever hit.

Is there something wrong with the approach itself? If so, what could I do to fix it?

Comment: `Other controllers seem to be firing before the CurrentUser controller is ever hit` - Are `other controllers` controller(s) that are hit when the browser executes a Get/Post or do you mean controllers that are executed on when the View is composed after the incoming action has been handled (during composition of ActionResult/ViewResult)?

Comment: We created a custom class with role properties that is populated when the user logs in.  Then this class is stored in the session.  You can combine this approach with overriding `AuthorizeCore` to use the built in MVC authorization attributes

Comment: It is risky to depend on the order of execution in this manner.  Even if you get it to work now, the code becomes brittle because a change to the layout file could cause the order of operations to change.

What are you storing in `TempData`?  How are you creating and storing the tokens?  The built-in authentication mechanisms have a way to securely store custom principal data, but if you are doing this manually those might not be available to you.

Comment: It's true that I am currently depending on the layout file to set the order controllers are fired. Consider the signed-in ho,e page. It has `CurrentUser` and body content which contain all `HttpGet` actions.

Comment: @stephen.vakil: Token creation is a through a custom algorithm and stored as a hashed, base64 encoded string in either a cookie or local storage. We're targeting a stateless system and I'd lke to explore what mechanisms MVC has built-in for user validation against our custom database.